# Multiple non-nested if conditions in list comprehension without a terminal else

Tags: python, list-comprehension

*(Note: before you jump the gun to look for duplicate if-else Q's, please see the next section for why many of them did not suit mine)*

I want to learn how to use list comprehension to simplify the two set of code block into one:

```
    filenameslist.extend(
    [f[:-4] for f in filenames if (
        f.endswith('.mp3') or
        f.endswith('.wma') or
        f.endswith('.aac') or
        f.endswith('.ogg') or
        f.endswith('.m4a')
    )])

    filenameslist.extend(
        [f[:-5] for f in filenames if (
            f.endswith('.opus')
    )])
```

---

I have tried to achieve it using the following code after following so many answers here in SO. However, these doesn't work for me. Please have a look at what I have right now:

```
    filenameslist.extend(
    [(f[:-4] if (
        f.endswith('.mp3') or
        f.endswith('.wma') or
        f.endswith('.aac') or
        f.endswith('.ogg') or
        f.endswith('.m4a')
    ) else (f[:-5] if f.endswith('.opus') else '')) for f in filenames])
```

The unnecessary `else ''` at the end adds an entry '' to my list which I don't need. Removing the else or using `else pass` results in syntax error.

I can delete the `''` entry manually from list, but the point is to learn how to do this one-step with list comprehension. I am using py 3.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in the expression of your list comprehension to state something like "do not produce an item in that case" (when the extension is not your list of allowed extensions).

You have to somehow repeat your test:

```py
filenames = ['test.mp3', 'something.opus', 'dontcare.wav']
l = [
    f[:-5] if f.endswith('.opus') else f[:-4]
     for f in filenames
     if (
             f.endswith('.mp3') or
             f.endswith('.wma') or
             f.endswith('.aac') or
             f.endswith('.ogg') or
             f.endswith('.m4a') or
             f.endswith('.opus')
     )
]
print(l)
```

Note that you can use `os.path.splitext` to ease your work:

```py
import os
filenames = ['test.mp3', 'something.opus', 'dontcare.wav']
l = [
    os.path.splitext(f)[0]
     for f in filenames
     if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in ['.mp3', '.wma', '.aac', '.ogg', '.m4a', '.opus']
]
print(l)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the correction in my existing method in addition to an easier approach. I have selected it as answer because of the help with correction. Other answers here are better, if one is just looking for simpler alternatives (that too without any additional library import). But I really benefitted seeing what I missed in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) objects' built-in properties instead of parsing the names yourself:

```py
from pathlib import Path

filenames = Path('/some/folder/').glob('*')
allowed_suffixes = ['.mp3', '.wma', '.aac', '.ogg', '.m4a', '.opus']
file_stems = set(f.stem for f in filenames if f.suffix in allowed_suffixes)
```

You can use a list instead of a set, of course. This looks cleaner than a convoluted list comprehension. If you want to retain the files' full paths, use:

```py
file_stems = set(f.parent / f.stem for f in filenames if f.suffix in allowed_suffixes)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) method can optionally take a tuple of suffixes, so you can simply do:

```
allowed_suffixes = '.mp3', '.wma', '.aac', '.ogg', '.m4a', '.opus'
filenameslist.extend(f[:f.rfind('.')] for f in filenames if f.endswith(allowed_suffixes))
```

Comment: Simplest alternative I have got till now, without needing extra import.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rpartition`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rpartition.html) like below:

```
filenameslist.extend([fn.rpartition('.')[0] for fn in filenames if fn[fn.rfind('.'):] in suffixes])
```

**Example:**

```
suffixes = ['.mp3', '.wma', '.aac', '.ogg', '.m4a', '.opus', '.wav']

filenames = ['test.mp3', 'something.opus', 'dontcare.wav', 'lara']

[fn.rpartition('.')[0] for fn in filenames if fn[fn.rfind('.'):] in suffixes]
```

Output:

```
['test', 'something', 'dontcare']
```

Comment: I have made an edit to replace `find('.')` with `rfind('.')`. If the filename contains `.` before `.extension`, rfind() still works. For example: thisis.afile.name.txt